# Measuring the % of pectin in a fibre after enzymatic treatment with pectinase

Tags: spectrophotometry, enzymes

I will remove the pectin from hemp fibres with Bioprep 3000L pectinase. How can I measure the % of pectin before and after for loose fibres? I only found a way to measure it for fabric, but I will perform this test on just loose hemp fibres.

Comment: The meter for measurement for fabrics is called: ruthenium red dye method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that I do not have professional experience in the textile industry!*

Supposed that the stems have been (mechanically) treated, and the "bark" is removed, the *ruthenium red method* should work.

In *Crystal-Structure of Ruthenium Red and Stereochemistry of its Pectic Stain* by *Clarence Sterling*, *Am. J. Bot.* **1970**, *57*, 172-175, the specific binding of Ruthenium Red (**RR**, CAS-RN: 11103-72-3) along a pectin chain, that is, between a $\ce{COOH}$ of one galacturonic acid unit and the $\ce{OH}$ of the next, has been described.

In a more recent publication, *Qualitative distinction of carboxyl group distributions in pectins with ruthenium red*, published in *Bot. Bull. Acad. Sin.*, **1999**, *40*, 115-119 ([PDF](http://ejournal.sinica.edu.tw/bbas/content/1999/2/bot402-02.pdf)), the method was applied to orange peel pectines of different origin. Here, the dye-pectin adducts were precipitated by addition of $\ce{CaCl2}$ and centrifugated. Then, the absorbtion of the supernatant solution and a stock solution of the dye at $\lambda = 534\,\mathrm{nm}$ were compared.

Consequently, it should be possible to take fibre samples, suspend them and detemine whether they decrease the absorption of **RR** (= still contain pectin).

Are you planning to bleach these fibres in a way recently discussed in another question? It might be interesting to figure out whether these conditions (alkaline hydroperoxide) are sufficent to (partly) degrade the pectin.